# Error: Descriptors cannot not be created directly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

Suddently i got this error , even i have downgrade protobuf==3.19.6 still i got this below error
TypeError: Descriptors cannot not be created directly.
If this call came from a _pb2.py file, your generated code is out of date and must be regenerated with protoc >= 3.19.0.
If you cannot immediately regenerate your protos, some other possible workarounds are:

1. Downgrade the protobuf package to 3.20.x or lower.
2. Set PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python (but this will use pure-Python parsing and will be much slower).

I try to dowgrade protobuf==3.19.6